# npm module with multiple sub modules, each with a set of functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know there are multiple results with looking for something like this but I don't seem to get them or I'm not sure how to implement them into my use case.

I'm planning on creating an npm package with multiple sub modules: `foo` and `bar`

When I use the package on an app i would like to be able to do

```
import { foo, bar } from 'module';
```

which allows me to gain access of different functions from each "module" and use them like so

```
foo.Add(1,2); // 3
foo.Sub(1,2); // 1

bar.Multiply(1,2); // 2
bar.Divide(1,2); // 2
```

From the **Example 4** in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29566143/4620773), what I envisioned looks something similar but instead my functions are not accessed directly. My situation is like exporting the export??

Is this possible? I feel like I haven't used a package that is like this or i just don't remember. And I think this might be easy to accomplish, I just dont know how to start

Comment: And why don't you comment on those solutions to ask for further details and improve those answers? What happens here is we add yet another variation of the same answers that already exist.

Comment: Most of them are just importing the `functions()` right away that's why I didn't bother. But I will add them anyhow

Comment: And how are you exporting foo and bar?

Comment: Look [at these examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Examples). Specifically, look at how they are exporting the `graph` object. That's what you need

Comment: The examples you gave is same as the example that put in the question. It's just importing the `cube()` right away. My goal is `foo.cube()`

Comment: you speak about cube when I told you to look at graph? Wow... good luck man

Comment: Ohh yeah. My bad. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Export as const should work

```
export const foo = {
    Add: function(x, y)  {
       /** todo add **/
    },
    Sub: function(x, y) {
      /** todo sub **/
    }
}

export const bar = {
   Multiply: function(x, y) {
     /** todo multiply **/
   }, 
   Divide: function (x, y) {
       /** todo divide **/
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you read this quite informative info about [module.Exports in nodeJS](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) and the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) on nodeJS - This guide will defininitly provide an answer to your problem.

Here is an example:

someModule.js

```
module.exports.someFunctionName1 = function(arg1,arg2,argN) {
    doSomeThing/returnSomeThing
}

module.exports.someFunctionName2 = function() {
    doSomeThing/returnSomeThing
}
```

someApp.js

```
import { someFunctionName1,someFunctionName2} from 'someModule.js'; 

var result = someFunctionName1(1,2,3);
```

Hope that helps..